# Probability - Flu test using Bayes Rule

Tags: math, probability, bayesian

I have the following question:

*You go to the doctor about a strong headache. The doctor randomly selects you for a blood test for flu, which is suspected to affect 1 in 9,000 people in your city. The accuracy of the test is 99%, meaning that the probability of a false positive is 1%. The probability of a false negative is zero. Given that you test positive, what is the probability that you have flu?*

In this question, could someone help me understand that would what would the P(Positive|Flu) would be? Would it be 1 or .99?

Answer (score 3):

P(+|Flu) = 0.99. But the question is somewhat misleading and really cannot be solved unless we know the prevalence of flu among people with strong headaches, since not everyone has a strong headache in the population. The prevalence of flu in the population is 1 in 9000. But you have a strong headache, which probably means you have a slightly higher probability of actually having the flu than, say, your friend who doesn't have a strong headache. Anyway,...

Bayes' Rule says: P(Flu|+) = P(+|Flu) x P(Flu) / P(+)

---

**Information known**:

P(Flu) = 1/9000

P(+|no Flu) = 0.01 (False positive rate)

P(-|Flu) = 0 (False negative rate)

---

We need P(+). Using the total law of probability, we can calculate it.

P(+) = P(+|Flu) x P(Flu) + P(+|no Flu) x P(no Flu) = 0.99x1/9000 + 0.01x8999/9000 = 0.01088

So, P(Flu|+) = 0.99 x 1/9000 / 0.01088 = 0.0109 or about 1.1%. So you're unlikely to have the flu, even after the positive test. Why? Because the prevalence of flu is very low (~0.0001) and the test is not perfect (1 in 100 without flu will test +).

Moral of the story? Don't screen for flu among the general population. Only screen those at high risk or those who show symptoms (like headache **AND** fever + cough), in which case the prevalence of flu would be much higher than 1 in 9,000, probably 1 in 20. Change the prevalence to 1 in 20 and your risk of flu given a + test result would jump to 84%.